# Can OKTA be used as IDP for Salesforce API access (machine to machine)

Tags: oauth-2.0, salesforce, okta, mulesoft, idp

Full disclosure, I'm not an expert in OKTA, IDP technologies, or Salesforce API security configuration.

I'm working with a client that wants to secure Salesforce APIs via OKTA. They are currently using OKTA for SSO for their user access, but the ask now is to authorize API access using OKTA. We use MuleSoft to integrate with Salesforce and the client is asking us to request an access token from OKTA to submit to Salesforce to access the APIs via OAuth2 or OpenID. We are currently doing this against Salesforce (OAuth2) as IDP, but the ask is to use OKTA as the IDP for API authorization.
[Requested flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LpNR.png)

We have tried to follow [this](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/12/23/mulesoft-salesforce-integration) guide to implement this functionality, but it doesn't work for us. It seems like this is creating a configuration for the other direction (ie. Salesforce -> MuleSoft APIs).

Does anyone know if what we're seeking is possible? I'm unable to find any other guides and we've heard from some Salesforce architects (unrelated projects) that this is not possible.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to protect Salesforce API using OKTA as your IDP. If that is correct, you might need to configure Salesforce to use OKTA as the external IDP. You can follow what is described here https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/12/23/mulesoft-salesforce-integration#integrate-okta-as-an-oidc-provider-within-salesforce this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.